# Magento 2.4 getting this error. is anyone guide me please

Tags: magento2.3

[image]

> [Report Only] Refused to load the image
> 'https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=350606009147220&ev=SubscribedButtonClick&dl=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2FCE%2Fsuprememed%2Fsleeve-lymphedema-full-arm-26-75&rl=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2FCE%2Fsuprememed%2Fmedical-supply%2Fapparel%2Fcompression-garments%2Flymphedema&if=false&ts=1614343042846&cd[buttonFeatures]=%7B%22classList%22%3A%22fotorama__nav__frame%20fotorama__nav__frame--thumb%20fotorama__active%22%2C%22destination%22%3A%22%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22%22%2C%22imageUrl%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2FCE%2Fsuprememe...%2Fmedia%2Fcatalog%2Fproduct%2Fcache%2F88879fe77cf9b607d6864a47e51235b9%2Fm%2Fj%2Fmj10-red_main_1_5.jpg%22%2C%22innerText%22%3A%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%5Cn%22%2C%22numChildButtons%22%3A0%2C%22tag%22%3A%22div%22%7D&cd[buttonText]=%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0A&cd[formFeatures]=%5B%5D&cd[pageFeatures]=%7B%22title%22%3A%22SLEEVE%2C%20LYMPHEDEMA%20FULL%20ARM%2026.75%5C%22%22%7D&cd[parameters]=%5B%5D&sw=1360&sh=768&v=2.9.33&r=stable&ec=2&o=2078&it=1614343029023&coo=false&es=automatic&tm=3&rqm=GET'
> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "img-src widgets.magentocommerce.com [www.googleadservices.com](http://www.googleadservices.com)
> [www.google-analytics.com](http://www.google-analytics.com) [www.paypalobjects.com](http://www.paypalobjects.com) t.paypal.com
> [www.paypal.com](http://www.paypal.com) fpdbs.paypal.com fpdbs.sandbox.paypal.com
> *.vimeocdn.com s.ytimg.com d3sbl0c71oxeok.cloudfront.net dhkkzdfmpzvap.cloudfront.net d2bpzs5y44q6e0.cloudfront.net
> d37shgu97oizpd.cloudfront.net d1zlqll3enr74n.cloudfront.net
> d1jynp0fpwn93a.cloudfront.net d2cb3tokgpwh3v.cloudfront.net
> d1re8bfxx3pw6e.cloudfront.net d35u8xwkxs8vpe.cloudfront.net
> d13s9xffygp5o.cloudfront.net d388nbw0dwi1jm.cloudfront.net
> d11p2vtu3dppaw.cloudfront.net d3r89hiip86hka.cloudfront.net
> dc7snq0c8ipyk.cloudfront.net d5c7kvljggzso.cloudfront.net
> d2h8yg3ypfzua1.cloudfront.net d1b556x7apj5fb.cloudfront.net
> draz1ib3z71v2.cloudfront.net dr6hdp4s5yzfc.cloudfront.net
> d2bomicxw8p7ii.cloudfront.net d3aypcdgvjnnam.cloudfront.net
> d2a3iuf10348gy.cloudfront.net *.ssl-images-amazon.com
> *.ssl-images-amazon.co.uk *.ssl-images-amazon.co.jp *.ssl-images-amazon.jp *.ssl-images-amazon.it *.ssl-images-amazon.fr *.ssl-images-amazon.es *.media-amazon.com *.media-amazon.co.uk *.media-amazon.co.jp *.media-amazon.jp *.media-amazon.it *.media-amazon.fr *.media-amazon.es *.cloudflare.com *.klarna.com *.googleadservices.com *.google-analytics.com *.paypal.com *.twitter.com *.twimg.com *.ytimg.com 'self' data: *.lightemporium.com *.usercentrics.eu yotpo.com [www.yotpo.com](http://www.yotpo.com) p.yotpo.com staticw2.yotpo.com w2.yotpo.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error showing because of **Magento Content Security Policies**. You can check detailed info about Magento Content Security Policies at the Magento Official link.
**https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html**

If you don't want to use this feature of Magento then you can simply disable this module by the below command.

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_Csp
```